# character "@" in the name of a variable in the django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a dictionary in my views.py

```
mydata = {'@model': 'wolfen', '@genre': 'fantastic', 'price: '350'}
```

which I pass to the django view in a context like this

```
context['mydata'] = mydata
```

and in my view i display like this

```
{{mydata.@model}}
```

the problem is that the django template uses the "@" character for other tags.
How to replace the "@" character to not display the following error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '@model' from 'mydata.@model'
```

thank you

the solution of Willem work fine.

I have another nested dictionary that looks different

```
mydata_2 ={'1' {'@model': 'wolfen', '@genre': 'fantastic', 'price': '300'} , {'3' {'@model': 'phase4', '@genre': 'fantastic', 'price': '450'} }
```

the keys of the main dictionaries ("1" , "3") can change dynamically.

otherwise a big thank you to Willem

Comment: can you show more code of your template? it's working for me if iterate over the dictionary object.

Comment: it works very well for me too.
I edited my question because I have a second (nested) dictionary and Willem's solution doesn't work.

Comment: now all problems are solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the data, for example with:

```
mydata = {'@model': 'wolfen', '@genre': 'fantastic', 'price': '350'}
mydata = {k[1:] if k.startswith('@') else k: v for k, v in mydata.items()}
context['mydata'] = mydata
```

Then you can use `{{ mydata.model }}` in the template.

Or for subdictionaries:

```
mydata_2 = {
    '1': {'@model': 'wolfen', '@genre': 'fantastic', 'price': '300'},
    '3': {'@model': 'phase4', '@genre': 'fantastic', 'price': '450'},
}
mydata_2 = {
    k: {ki[1:] if ki.startswith('@') else ki: v for ki, v in subdict.items()}
    for k, subdict in mydata_2.items()
}
```

Comment: thank you Willem, it works very well. I edited my question because I have another nested dictionary that looks different

Comment: Perfect. It works very well. A double big thank you Willem.